# How to prevent from drawing outside of a floating window on Android

Tags: android, camera

I have to crop a camera preview on Android.

Camera preview is drawing its views on a surface, from a surfaceholder. Of course I use a SurfaceView.
To crop the preview, I put the SurfaceView in a custom ViewGroup. I can manage the size of this custom ViewGroup by overwriting onMeasure() and the size of the inside surface while overwriting onLayout().

```
@overrides
void onMeasure(...) {
    // do sgt to compute the size of the component
}

@overrides
void onLayout(int l, int t, int b, int r) {
    mSurfaceView.layout(l-100,t-100,b+100,r+100)
}
```

It works fine ! the video is clipped, 100px on each side.

Now, I need to put this in a floating window. And the problem is that it's clippling very well INSIDE of the floating window. But outside of the floating window, it's a complete mess. I Even tried to clip the canvas, even with this solution, the preview is correctly clipped in the window, but it's still drawing outside of the window.

[[image]]

I almost tried every kind of ...clip... and ...crop... parameters. Nothing is working.

Here is a short Activity code to test on your device :

```
public class FloatingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GameView v = new GameView(this);

        camera = Camera.open(id)
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        setContentView(v);
    }


    public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
        private SurfaceHolder holder;

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
                    camera.startPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                           int width, int height) {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            super.layout(-200, -200, 600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int save = canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(300,300,700,700);
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(save);
        }
    }


}
```

Just in case, here is my activity declaration in the manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.FloatingActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_floating"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" >
</activity>
```